# Why does Google Scholar combine my journal paper with its arXiv version only in my profile?

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar

I authored a journal paper, of which I've also uploaded a version to arXiv. The title and the content of the two versions are same, only the layout is different. In my Google Scholar Citations profile the two versions are "merged" as one paper. But when I perform a search for the paper, or with my name, Google Scholar shows the two versions separately, with separate citation counts (8 for the journal, 2 for the arXiv manuscript).

However, if one looks at my Google Scholar Citations profile, they see only one paper (containing the arXiv manuscript as one version), and with citation count 10. Obviously, this is what I'd want to be seen whenever someone searches for the paper -- the combined citation count, and the possibility to download the arXiv version pdf for free. How can I make Google Scholar present the paper in a search in the same way as it presents it in my profile?

Comment: GS? Goldman Sachs? Geological Society? Columbia's school of General Studies? And what is it that leads you to believe that you'd have the ability to change it?

Comment: It is rather unlikely somebody here can answer your question. You'd have to ask Google Scholar.

Comment: I have an answer to offer: You need to keep two things clearly distinct: Google Scholar (GS) general search results, and your personal GS profile. The GS search results indexes articles that Google finds on the Web, and lists the number of citations for each article. If two articles are found separately, GS search results will always list them separately. In contrast, your profile is just what you would like people to see. Google graciously lets you customize how people see things in your profile, but this doesn't change the reality on the Web that there are two different articles out there.

Comment: I don't have voting rights, but I think the question is interesting enough to enough readers that it should be allowed. There is quite a community here on Academia SE that is very interested in the ins and outs of Google Scholar, and I don't know of any better place on the Web to get answers to questions like this one. To respond to "You'd have to ask Google Scholar", I don't think they would be very responsive if the answer isn't already on an FAQ.